# Recommend way to loading a large lookup table/index for a Play application

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new to the Play framework.

I've a command line application (in Java) that loads a large index (about 6GB) in memory which is then use to really quick looks ups. I'm trying to add a REST wrapper around this using the Play framework (Scala).

My question are there any recommendations/best practices in terms of where and how I should handle the loading of this index so that it done only once at startup and is alive throughout the application life cycle?

Thanks.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631827/how-to-execute-on-start-code-in-scala-play-framework-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Global object which let's you do initialization tasks,
link to official docs http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaGlobal

Comment: This work and loads my lookup table in memory. My next question is how to access the "val" that is loaded in the Global object ?

Comment: I'm not quite understand, Global is scala singleton object, reference it as any other object Global.variablename

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the loading logic inside the `onStart` method of a custom defined plugin :

```
class IndexPLugin(app: Application) extends Plugin {
  private var index:Index

  override def onStart() {
    // perform the loading here
    // the app parameter gives you access to the application configuration
  }

  def queryData():Data {
    // this public method gives your client access to the loaded data
  }
}
```